# How to join string in kotlin and add postfix only if more than 1 item

Tags: java, arrays, string, kotlin

I have a list of some data class which I want to join into a string in kotlin EFFICIENTLY (least amount of code).

the data class is:

```
data class Animal(val name: String, val description: String)
```

and I am getting a `List<Animal>` in some other class where I want to turn the list into string to display as per follows:

if list only one item (eg `[Animal(name: "Dog", description: "Good dog, age 2 years"]`) then display name only on one line:

```
Dog
```

if more than 1 item in list (eg `[Dog, Cat, Mouse]`) then display with one line after each animal name like:

```
Dog

Cat

Mouse
```

I have done this in code as per following statement/s but it is very ugly + hard to read... so want to ask how can I do the same thing in more efficient neater way..

solution A:

```
animals.joinToString("\n\n") { it.name } + if (animals.size > 1) "\n" else ""
```

solution B:

```
animals.joinToString(separator = "\n\n", postfix = if (animals.size > 1) "\n" else "") { it.name }
```

please suggest how to improve this..

Comment: I'd say solution B is likely as "efficient" (in terms of Lines of Code) as you can get.  That looks like the exact usage of the joinToString and postfix parameter.  If you dont like how this looks in your code, I suggest just wrapping it in a helper function, and call that function whatever you want to make your code nice and readable :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 2 cases it's difficult to compact this logic much further but I found this to be as "neat" as I can produce:

```
animals.takeIf { size == 1 }?.get(0)?.name?:animals.joinToString(separator = "\n\n", postfix = "\n"){it.name}
```